# When I do ng serve it gives me an error of maximun call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular

I have a project folder with the next parts: User and Artist
It is suppose to be a multi app.

artists app.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    DashboardModule,
 SharedModule,
 HttpClientModule,
 ToastrModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},

    {
        provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: HttpErrorInterceptorService,
        multi: true
    },
    AlertifyService,
    AuthService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

@NgModule({})
export class App2SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<AppModule>{
    return {
      ngModule: AppModule,
      providers: []
    };
  }
}
```

user app.module

```
 App2SharedModule.forRoot()
```

user app-roting

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { App2SharedModule } from '../../../artists/src/app/app.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)},
  { path: 'artists', loadChildren: () => import('../../../artists/src/app/app.module').then(m => m.App2SharedModule)},

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes),App2SharedModule.forRoot()],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When I run ng serve it shows the next error:

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js): Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this kind of errors? And if so, could you tell me whats wrong on my code?

Comment: Do you have recursive function in your app? I think the issue isn't about AppModule.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't return the root AppModule in a different module like that. What was the idea behind doing so? You're basically bootstrapping a module that bootstraps a module that bootstraps a module…

Answer (score 1):

Today i had the same problem, i fixed it using:

At AppModule:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule ({ 
 declarations: [yours],
 imports: [yours + ReactiveFormsModule],
 providers: [yours],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```